# Java TreeMap within TreeMap - Identifier error?

Tags: java, treemap, treemaps

This works fine:

```
TreeMap <String, ArrayList> x_probs_org = new TreeMap<String, ArrayList>();
```

But this:

```
TreeMap <String, TreeMap<String, Float>> x_probs = new <String, TreeMap<String, Float>>();
```

causes the following error:

```
error: <identifier> expected
```

Why? What am I doing wrong? I tried a couple of other ways but I don't see why this is wrong.

Comment: Note, rare types are bad - you want to make your `ArrayList` generic argument generic. Also it's conventional to use the interface type for the type of variables and parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the `TreeMap` identifier:

```
.... = new TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, Float>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

try it like that:

```
TreeMap <String, TreeMap<String, Float>> x_probs = new TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, Float>>();
```